# How to make sequences that may be empty?

Tags: r, list, sorting, sequence, quicksort

I recently tried to adapt [some pseudocode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort) for an in-place quicksort, quoted below:

```
function quicksort(array)
    if length(array) > 1
        pivot := select any element of array
        left := first index of array
        right := last index of array
        while left ≤ right
            while array[left] < pivot
                left := left + 1
            while array[right] > pivot
                right := right - 1
            if left ≤ right
                swap array[left] with array[right]
                left := left + 1
                right := right - 1
        quicksort(array from first index to right)
        quicksort(array from left to last index)
```

Following this, I wrote this code:

```
quicksort<-function(array)
{
  len<-length(array)
  if(len>1)
  {
    left<-1
    right<-len
    pivot<-array[(left+right)%/%2]
    while(left<=right)
    {
      while(array[left]<pivot){left<-left+1}
      while(array[right]<pivot){right<-right-1}
      if(left<=right)
      {
        array[c(left,right)]<-array[c(right,left)]
        left<-left+1
        right<-right-1
      }
    }
    array<-quicksort(array[1:right])#Bug here
    array<-quicksort(array[left:len])
  }
  array
}
```

If you run this code with more than one integer as an input, you'll find that it eventually tries to sort lists of NAs. I suspect that the problem is that the pseduocode wants `array from first index to right` - my `1:right` - to be read as an empty sequence when `right` is zero. As is well known, R would actually read as `1:0` as the sequence `0 1`.

Is there any function to get the behavior that I intend? I could do this with an if statement, but R is usually good enough with sequences that I can't help but think that there will be a better way. I tried to use `seq`, but it will throw an error if you try to use anything like `seq(from=1,to=0,by=1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the code:

1. One of the inequality signs is flipped.
2. The array assignment needs to be modified to only change a subset of elements rather than replace (and shrink) the whole array.

Here is the corrected code

```
quicksort <- function(array) {
  len <- length(array)
  if(len > 1) {
    left <- 1
    right <- len
    pivot <- array[(left+right)%/%2]
    while(left <= right)
    {
      while(array[left] < pivot){ 
        left <- left + 1
      }
      while(array[right] > pivot) { # Changed "<" to ">"
        right <- right - 1
      }
      if(left <= right) {
        array[c(left, right)] <- array[c(right, left)]
        left <- left + 1
        right <- right - 1
      }
    }
    
    # Modified the following two lines to only set a subset of array
    array[1:right] <- quicksort(array[1:right])
    array[left:len] <- quicksort(array[left:len])
  }
  array
}


quicksort(c(2, 6, 3, 1, 4, 5))
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```